# load mesh to rviz and "publish current scene" no effect MoveIt!

Tags: rviz, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I work with MoveIt!, instead of loading objects from the tabs in Rviz GUI, I loaded a mesh model into rviz using C++ code (visualization marker) and the loading was successful, I can see the object was there in Rviz. But after I clicked "publish current scene" the planning scene did not take into account the object in terms of collision detection and path planning. Could anyone shed light on how I can make sure the planning scene is aware of the loaded object? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212714/load-mesh-to-rviz-and-%22publish-current-scene%22-no-effect-moveit!/) by [Huitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22131/huitan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-07-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RViz != MoveIt. There is no *direct* connection between RViz and MoveIt's internal models. A visualisation marker is just that, a marker for RViz.

To get objects registered in the Planning Scene, see fi [ROS moveit programmatically adding collision object](http://answers.ros.org/question/56466/ros-moveit-programmatically-adding-collision-object/), the MoveIt Environment API [examples](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Environment_Representation/ROS_API) or [any of the messages](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/moveit-users/planning$20scene) on the `moveit-users` list.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1